# Why this piece of code is giving me desired output,it should return True if the sequence of numbers is 1, 2, 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
          if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+3]==3:
            return True
    return False
x=arrayCheck([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
print(x)
```

Comment: `nums[i+3]` should be `nums[i+2]`, voting to close as a typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+3]==3
```

Perhaps you meant `i+2` instead of `i+3`?

```
if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3
```